# pigeon hole / multiple numbers

Tags: c++

```
input : integer ( i'll call it N ) and (1 <= N <= 5,000,000 )
output : integer, multiple of N and only contains 0,7 

Ex.
Q1 input : 1 -> output : 7 ( 7 mod 1 == 0 )
Q2 input : 2 -> output : 70  ( 70 mod 2 == 0 )

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

int remaind(string num, ll m)
{
    ll mod = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) {
        int digit = num[i] - '0';
        mod = mod * 10 + digit;
        mod = mod % m;
    }
    return mod;
}



int main()
{
    int n;
    string ans;
    cin >> n;
    ans.append(n, '7');
    for (int i = ans.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (remaind(ans, n) == 0)
        {
            cout << ans;
            return 0;
        }
        ans.at(i) = '0';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

is there a way to lessen the time complexity?

i just tried very hard and it takes little bit more time to run while n is more than 1000000

ps. changed code
ps2. changed code again because of wrong code
ps3. optimize code again
ps4. rewrite post

Comment: Please don’t edit the question into an answer, or add _solved_ in the title. To mark a question as solved accept one of the answers. If you solved it yourself _you_ can post an answer and accept it.

Comment: You don't need to add `solved` to the title; the right way to indicate that you've solved your problem is accepting an answer, which you aready did. Also, please don't add the solution you ended up with to the question. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong, let's say you divide "70" by 5. Then you result will be 2 which is not right (just analyze your code to see why that happens).

You can really base your search upon numbers like 77777770000000, but think more about that - which numbers you need to add zeros and which numbers you do not.

Next, do not use strings! Think of reminder for a * b if you know reminder of a and reminder of b. When you program it, be careful with integer size, use 64 bit integers.

Now, what about a + b?

Finally, find reminders for numbers 10, 100, 1000, 10000, etc (once again, do not use strings and still try to find reminder for any power of 10).

Well, if you do all that, you'll be able to easily solve the whole problem.

Comment: but, if N is something like 4,999,999,  answer can easily get over ( long long ) type             and that is why i used a string as an output.

Comment: yes we can, consider numbers a = 3,456,789 and b = 2,345,678 and try to find (a * b) % 4,999,999. Can you do it with 64 bit int? Now, what about ((a * b)*(a * b)) % 4,999,999? You have to think, this is not that easy task, but not too hard

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend any of the [boost::bignum](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) integer classes?

I suspect `uint1024_t` (or whatever... they also have 128, 256, and 512, bit ints already typedefed, and you can declare your own easily enough) will meet your needs, allowing you to perform a single `%`, rather than one per iteration.  This may outweigh the performance lost when using bignum vs c++'s built-in ints.

2^1024 ~= 1.8e+308.  Enough to represent any 308 digit number.  That's probably excessive.

2^512 ~= 1.34e+154.  Good for any 154 digit number.

etc.

I suspect you should first write a loop that went through n = 4e+6 -> 5e+6 and wrote out which string got the longest, then size your uint*_t appropriately.  If that longest string length is more than 308 characters, you could just whip up your own:

```
typedef number<cpp_int_backend<LENGTH, LENGTH, unsigned_magnitude, unchecked, void> > myReallyUnsignedBigInt;
```

The modulo operator is probably the most expensive operation in that inner loop.  Performing once per iteration on the outer loop rather than at the inner loop (O(n) vs O(n^2)) should save you quite a bit of time.

Will that plus the whole "not going to and from strings" thing pay for bignum's overhead?  You'll have to try it and see.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer and sorry for that i didnt edit my post properly. i actually solved this question with string.